# Access Notification Bar without pulling down from the top of the screen

Tags: android, lg

So I'm currently rocking an LG G3 of about 2 years which is due for an upgrade, but I currently lack funds to purchase said upgrade for a bit of time because college. Due to (most likely) numerous reasons, roughly the top 10th of the screen is insensitive to touch (as well as some other spots).

One of my favorite features of Android phones is how quick and easy using the notification pull down is to change settings and, well, check notifications. With the current defect, not only is it impossible to pull down the Notification bar, but also difficult to turn on or off any of the quick settings, and not to mention the numerous in-app difficulties.

Does any one have any alternates to accessing the notification pull down without having to rotate to landscape view in a separate app and pulling down the bar from there?

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Display > Home Touch Buttons > Add icon that pulls down notifiaction bar
 [image]